# Error on defining an array even though its set via a Constant

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, constants

I know this is really basic, but its got me stumped...

In Objective-C I'm trying to write:

```
const int BUF_SIZE = 3;

static char buffer[BUF_SIZE+1];
```

But I get a storage size of buffer isn't constant. How do I make Xcode realise that I'm setting it to a constant, + 1...? Or is this not possible...?

Thanks...!

Joel

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a C thing—if I recall correctly, C only allows you to specify array sizes with literal expressions (no symbols whatsoever). I'd just use a `#define` constant as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks – I'd completely forgotten about #DEFINE... J

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum:

```
enum
{
    BUF_SIZE = 3
};
```

Or a macro

```
#define BUF_SIZE 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Happens in gcc with things like:

```
#define LPBUFFER_LGTH ((int) (2*MS25))
```

as well.
Workaround as above: hardcode the constant you want. I think the problem is with a 'define of a define' ie. twice.